# Phalcon: Unable to initialize module Module compiled with build windows 7 x64 Zend Server

Tags: php, phalcon, php-extension, zend-server, php-5.5

I'm trying to install Phalcon module on Windows 7 with running Zend Server.

Some useful information: php -v

```
 [30.09.2014 15:02:32 p12888/t2672 NOTICE] Successfully established connection the database
 PHP 5.5.13 (cli) (built: Jun 26 2014 12:03:16)
 Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
 Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
  with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
  with Zend Extension Manager v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2003-2014, by Zend Technogies
  with Zend Data Cache v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2004-2014, by Zend Technologies
  [loaded] [licensed] [disabled]
- with Zend Job Queue v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2004-2014, by Zend Technologies
[loaded] [not licensed] [disabled]
- with Zend Session Clustering v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2004-2014, by Zend Tecnologies [loaded][licensed] [disabled]
- with Zend Utils v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2004-2014, by Zend Technologies [licensed] [licensed] [enabled]
- with Zend Code Tracing v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2009-2014, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [enabled]
- with Zend Server Z-Ray v7.0.0, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [enabled]
- with Zend Monitor v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [disabled]
- with Zend Debugger v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [enabled]
- with Zend Page Cache v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2004-2014, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [disabled]
- with Zend Monitor UI v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2004-2014, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [enabled]
```

OS: Windows 7 X64

I'm downloading DLLs from http://phalconphp.com/en/download/windows and https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/tree/master

Zend sever is installed in program files x86 and I've tried install dlls what I get from logs is:

```
[30-Sep-2014 15:35:42] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: phalcon: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS,VC11
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS,VC9
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
[30-Sep-2014 15:35:44] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: phalcon: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS,VC11
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS,VC9
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
[30-Sep-2014 15:35:46] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: phalcon: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS,VC11
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS,VC9
These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
[30-Sep-2014 15:37:08] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\lib\phpext\php_phalcon.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
[30-Sep-2014 15:37:10] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\lib\phpext\php_phalcon.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
  [30-Sep-2014 15:38:28] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: phalcon: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS,VC11
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS,VC9
 These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
 [30-Sep-2014 15:38:30] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: phalcon: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS,VC11
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS,VC9
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
 [30-Sep-2014 15:38:32] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: phalcon: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS,VC11
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS,VC9
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

I get these errors for different DLLs which I try to install as PHP module. Do you have any clues how can I install it on Windows?

I've already installed some modules for example MONGO and it worked but I'm struggling with phalcon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using a pre-compiled PHP extension for windows you must match the API numbers (PHP version), thread safety on or off (ZTS or NTS), and the version of Visual Studio used for the compile

PHP    compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS,VC9

This information tells you that the zend server version of PHP you're using was compiled with VC9, has thread safety off (NTS) and requires the 20121212 version of PHP's internal APIs

Module compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS,VC11

This information tells you that the phalcon extension you downloaded was compiled with VC11 - but the API and thread safety settings are the same as the current PHP install.  Because one of the three things doesn't match, however, the extension won't load correctly.

Unfortunately phalcon does not provide pre-compiled versions of the extension for PHP 5.5, NTS, built with VC9 so you'll either need to build your own or ask the maintainers to add that version

Or use something other than Zend Server for your PHP

Comment: Thanks elizabeth for your answer, I've figured it out already and it's pretty messy to install it on my version of php, zend and windows.